# Get name, date and sum from orders in March

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ((orders_books 
JOIN books ON orders_books.id_book = books.id) 
JOIN orders ON orders_books.id_order=orders.id) 
JOIN users ON user_id=users.id 
WHERE date >='2019-03-1' AND date <= '2019-03-31';
```

Query result: https://image.prntscr.com/image/s3ngzzYrSd27mFib9HbLmA.png

I find number of orders:

```
SELECT name, date, SUM(book_price) 
FROM ((orders_books 
INNER JOIN books ON orders_books.id_book = books.id) 
INNER JOIN orders ON orders_books.id_order=orders.id) 
INNER JOIN users ON user_id=users.id 
WHERE date >='2019-03-1' AND date <= '2019-03-31';
```

[Amount for all orders] : https://image.prntscr.com/image/o88Hf4uKSHGuZ2ESUECzuA.png

But I need to find the order amount separately for each order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
SELECT id_order, SUM(book_price) 
FROM ((orders_books 
INNER JOIN books ON orders_books.id_book = books.id) 
INNER JOIN orders ON orders_books.id_order=orders.id) 
INNER JOIN users ON user_id=users.id 
WHERE date >='2019-03-1' AND date <= '2019-03-31'
GROUP BY id_order;
```

Comment: @АлександрСавкин glad to help;)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT orders.id, SUM(book_price) 
FROM ((orders_books 
INNER JOIN books ON orders_books.id_book = books.id) 
INNER JOIN orders ON orders_books.id_order=orders.id) 
INNER JOIN users ON user_id=users.id 
WHERE date >='2019-03-1' AND date <= '2019-03-31'
GROUP BY order_id;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.com! Please do not only provide code, add explanation of the key parts. You're writing the answer not only for the OP but also for all the people who will land here in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you need  the sum for order.id then use group by orders.id

```
    SELECT orders.id  SUM(book_price) 
    FROM orders_books 
    INNER JOIN books ON orders_books.id_book = books.id
    INNER JOIN orders ON orders_books.id_order=orders.id

    WHERE date >='2019-03-1' AND date <= '2019-03-31'
    group by orders.id
```